# Deploying and hosting scala in the cloud?

Tags: scala, scalability, cloud, non-relational-database

I am starting a web app considering scalability as one of the top priorities.
What would be the benefits of this:
cassandra
scala
lift

vs the traditional LAMP
on the cloud? Since from what I've read, please correct me, the cloud itself is scalable

I have never seen anyone deploy scala on the cloud before. Is it worth the effort to learn the platform? Is it ready for production use?

Comment: On AppEngine: http://goo.gl/Adtz from http://goo.gl/05QW My opinion, is that Java is a better choice than PHP for applications that must scale and Scala, being capable of efficiency equal to code written in native Java, makes it a suitable replacement for Java. The cloud's good providers provides for scalability but doesn't necessarily imply your application will scale well. In other words, you can easily write an application that can't scale or will cost a fortune in resources when scaled. Anymore, i think it's less about the backend framework and more about your application design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done properly, java/scala cloud deployment can be as painless as "regular" deployment.

Also bear in mind that Scala effectively deploys as though it were Java + a library, so any java-centric cloud solutions will be available to you (GWT, EC2, etc.)

I'd strongly recommend that you check out Stax if you want to go this route (and I strongly encourage you to do so).  I've already started using it for a couple of Scala applications (one using lift).  They're backed by EC2 and actually use Scala internally.  Deployment and testing is a piece of cake too.

Comment: http://stax.net/ or search "stax cloud" since searching for just "stax" mostly refers to StAX, The Streaming API for XML (at least, for me)

Comment: Searching for Stax I found that it was acquired by [Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/acquisitions/stax/) in December 2010.

Comment: Hi guys, what is an affordable solution (compared to PHP) to host some simple webservices written in Scala?

Answer (score 5):

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/scala) now lets you deploy scala webapps

Comment: Good thing about them, they have free sandbox as well and suports almost most of the languages.

Answer (score 1):

I work at [Clever Cloud](http://www.clever-cloud.com/) and you can also deploy Scala webapps on our platform ;)
Check out our latest website [scala-cloud.com](http://scala-cloud.com/)

This  PaaS platform can automatically scale up and down your application regarding your traffic. You can also finely customize if you want vertical, horizontal or both types of scalability. The consequence of this scaling is that you pay as you go : you only pay for your real consumption and not the potential one.

Deployment via git.

Non AWS, hosted in tier-4+ datacenters.

Free trial !

Comment: Unfortunately you dont have free simple configuration, which would be great for small poc projects

Answer (score 1):

I tried with AWS and GWT and nowadays working with Jelastic and even Jelastic is as well a great performer with Scala.

http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/07/08/getting-started-with-scala-sbt/